# Csv Field seach for value and move if found

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I have been tasked with parsing a free form field in a csv report. By free form I mean user entered, the entries are general correct. All I really have to do is search for a list of values and if one is found move the whole row to new csv file and only keep the found value.

This is what the field looks like:

[image]

Where the yellow highlighted value is the value I need and red is a mistake made. What would i use to search this field and find these values even if there is a mistake?

Comment: Use File.ReadAllLines to get the values in an array and then you can split the values according to spaces, after that you can check if 3rd cell in split array has string length of more than 4 then it is incorrect otherwise its correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could do some fancy regex, but for something this simple, couldn't you create a console app to simply go line-by-line, splitting on the space?

Like this:

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\theReport.csv");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var elements = line.Split(' ');
    if (elements[3] == "Something I Am Interested In")
    {
        //Do Something
    }    
}
```